# Python similar uniq -c command?

Tags: python, linux, sorting, uniq

Does python have a command similar to the linux command:

```
cat file.txt | sort -n | uniq -c
```

Where it sorts and calculates the frequency of a text file with integers on every new line, and will output in the form:

```
76539  1 
100441 2 
108637 3 
108874 4 
103580 5 
 91869 6 
 78458 7 
 61955 8 
 46100 9 
 32701 10 
 21111 11 
 13577 12 
  7747 13 
  4455 14 
  2309 15 
  1192 16 
   554 17 
   264 18 
   134 19 
    63 20 
    28 21 
    15 22 
    12 23 
     7 24 
     5 25
```

If not, can I just simply `os.system(cat file.txt | sort -n | uniq -c)` ?

Comment: `collections.Counter()` - it is not exactly `uniq -c` but very handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import collections

c = collections.Counter()

with open('file.txt') as f:
    for text in f:
        c.update( [int(text.strip())] )

c_sorted = sorted(c.most_common())

for key, val in c_sorted:
    print val, key
```

Comment: This only seems to output only the numbers 0 - 9

Comment: You didn't add `file.txt` to test it. Show some input data.

Comment: I found the problem - I forgot to use `[]` in `update()`

Answer (score 1):

Try **[collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)**

```
>>> import collections
>>> collections.Counter(['asdf', 'sdfg', 'asdf', 'qwer', 'sdfg', 'asdf'])
Counter({'asdf': 3, 'sdfg': 2, 'qwer': 1})
>>> collections.Counter(map(str.strip, open('file.txt').readlines()))
Counter({'spam': 5, 'hello': 3, 'world': 2, 'eggs': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['blah', 'blah2']
my_result = dict((key, len(list(word_group))) for key, word_group in groupby(sorted(words)))
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html

Might be worth considering, but the **return_counts** option was not available in older versions of the library, so depends on what's available to you.